# Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.createReadStream" in client code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image

I'm very new to react, and i'm trying to make an app  that takes an image from folder and upon pressing a generate button  creates an image variation with the help of DALL-E The url of the image is printed in the console. However, in the documentation from "openai" there is this function fs.createReadStream which React doesn't recognize. How could I replace this fs function with something else that reads an image from the folder?

```
    import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

    import fs from 'fs';
    import { useState } from "react";
    import "./App.css";

    function App() {
  
    const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_Open_AI_Key,
    });

    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

    const generateImage = async () => {
    const response = await openai.createImageVariation(
    fs.createReadStream("images/3.png"), 
    1,
    "1024x1024"
    );
    
    console.log(res.data.data[0].url);
    };
    return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={generateImage}>generate an image</button>
    </div>
    )  
    }

    export default App;
```